# Compare to list<String> using linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have 3 list List

```
ListMaster contains {1,2,3,4,....} ..getting populated from DB
List1 contains {1,3,4}
List2 contains {1,3,95}
```

how to check Which list items are present in master list using linq

Answer (score 5):

```
var inMaster = List1.Intersect(ListMaster);
```

or for both list :

```
var inMaster = List1.Intersect(List2).Intersect(ListMaster);
```

check if any item from list1, list2 exist in master

```
var existInMaster = inMaster.Any();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx):

```
var inMaster = ListMaster.Intersect(List1.Concat(List2));
```

If you want to know which are in `List1` which are not in the master-list, use `Except`:

```
var newInList1 = List1.Except(ListMaster);
```

and for `List2`:

```
var newInList2 = List2.Except(ListMaster);
```

> Can i use a list .all to check all item of a list in another list for
>   list of string

So you want to know if all items of one list are in another list. Then using `Except` + `Any` is much more efficient(if the lists are large) because `Intersect` and `Except` are using sets internally whereas `All` loops all elements.

So for example, does the master-list contain all strings of `List1` and `List2`?

```
bool allInMaster = !List1.Concat(List2).Except(ListMaster).Any();
```

Comment: can i use a list .all to check all item of a list in another list for list of string

Comment: `Enumerable.All` is much less efficient than using `Except` + `Any`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302032.aspx) method like;

> Produces the set intersection of two sequences by using the default
>   equality comparer to compare values.

```
var inMaster1 = List1.Intersect(ListMaster);
var inMaster2 = List2.Intersect(ListMaster);
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/MR2QDT).